# javascript get his url document

Tags: javascript, loading

can a javascript document know the url from where is being loaded (not the referer)
without url rewriting.

I load http://qqsd.foo/blabla.js loaded on my html page and I want my blabla.js script know this url and the parameters it could have passed.

Comment: Is window.location.href what you are looking for?

Comment: @bchubz that would be the referrer (the page on which the script is being loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
<script src="http://qqsd.foo/blabla.js" id="blabla"></script>
```

then in your blabla.js file

```
alert(document.getElementById("blabla").getAttribute("src"))
```